# Hashtable compile time

Tags: c++, constexpr, compile-time

Today i'm trying to made an hashtable at both compile and run time.
But i'm not really familiar with constexpr, and i didn't find what i want on Internet.

There is my code:

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_HPP
#define HASHTABLE_HPP

#include  <cstddef>
#include  <vector>
#include  <string>

namespace  base
{
  template <typename K, typename V>
  class  HashTable
  {
    constexpr  HashTable(const size_t size, const std::pair<K, V> data[])
            : _hsize(size), _rsize(size), _nodes(initNodes(data)) {}

    HashTable(size_t hsize): _hsize(hsize), _rsize(0) {}
    ~HashTable() = default;

    private:
      class  HashNode
      {
        public:
          constexpr HashNode(HashNode *next, K key, V data, int flags): _next(next),_key(key),
                                                                      _data(data),_flags(flags) {}
      public:
        HashNode*  _next;
        K          _key;
        V          _data;
        int        _flags;
      };

    private:
      size_t     _hsize;  // Size of nodes[]
      size_t     _rsize;  // Number of elements
      HashNode*  _nodes;

    private:
      unsigned  hash();
      constexpr HashNode*  initNodes(const std::pair<K, V> data[], const size_t size)
      {
      }

  public:
    void  emptyTable();
    void  fillTable();
    int   compareNodes(K, K);
    int   addNode(K, V);
    V     getNode(K);
    V     removeNode(K);
  };
}
#endif
```

Can i made something like that? But there is some problem with initNodes.
I'd like to compile with gcc 4.9 (gcc-clite).
Please, could you give me some advice?

Thanks anyway!
Have a nice day

EDIT:
More precision, i want to be able to init a const hashtable at compile-time. And if it's possible with the same class for run-time

Comment: I don't think it is possible: `constexpr` requires no side-effects.
Anyway, it is a good practice to include error message (from the compiler) in your question.

Comment: I'm not trying to compile it, i search some ideas ^^

Comment: `constexpr` does permit side effects in C++14.